# Spring WS & Validator interceptor

Tags: java, web-services, spring, spring-ws

I have a endpoint mapping a webservice which is used to insert in the dabatabase some keywords:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false,isolation= Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public Source saveKW(...).
```

The input is a request.

I would like to add  an interceptor on the method in order to validate the parameters.
this one will read some values from the DB.

i would like that this interceptor is EMBED in the transaction declared for the endpoint (or this opposite). In other words, i want them to be in the same transaction.

Ideally im looking for something like this with annotation:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false,isolation= Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
@validator("KeyWordValidaor.class")
public Source saveKW(...)
```

where `KeyWordValidaor` will be class validating the parameters.

Have you any idea or short examples to implements this like this way or in a other real way?

Comment: Who does the validation have to be inside the transaction? It sounds like your input validation is independent of the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The validation has to be inside the transaction because it is querying the database to test constraints for example.
I have already found my solution. Im using spring aop & i load dynamically the appropriate validator from the spring context throuh a map. (very & unknown feature  of autorwired unknow beans name in advance!).
Thanks to the order attribute ,it is inside the transaction.